# Calabash-ios: Run test physical device installed ipa without xcodeproj

Tags: ios, json, xcode, calabash

I am new with calabash-ios and have a dummy question is:

How possibly could I run a calabash test with real device which have installed ipa file (included calabash framework) and without xcodeproj?

Problem is I am doing QA and Dev only gives me ipa file to test without source code.

**UPDATE:**
I am able to run the ipa file in console and cucumber by adding BUNDLE_ID. And make sure the CFNetwork.framework is including in app framework to establish the connection.

But I got another problem to run the scenario:
1. When I run the command below:

```
DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.1.9:37265 NO_LAUNCH=1 BUNDLE_ID=com.example.appname DEVICE_TARGET=UDID cucumber
```

Then I got this error:

```
 A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)
  features/my_first.feature:8:in `Then I touch "LOG-IN/ CREATE ACCOUNT"'
```

all other steps was skipped

2. Then I run the console code

   ```
   DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.1.9:37265 NO_LAUNCH=1 BUNDLE_ID=com.example.appname DEVICE_TARGET=UDID calabash-ios console
   ```

Then I run server_version
I got reply back that said connection SUCCEED
But when I run start_test_server_in_background
It took me too long to wait and I see the app my physical device kept crashed and launch again and again until it stop as:

```
Unable to start. Make sure you've set APP_BUNDLE_PATH to a build supported by this simulator version
Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError: Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError: 

"Timed out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError.
 2015-10-01 10:49:41.634 instruments[15640:10558880] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
 2015-10-01 10:49:42.574 instruments[15640:10558978] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
 2015-10-01 10:49:42.577 instruments[15640:10558877] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
 Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug app
```

Anyone can help please! I tried to search some solution but they almost issue on simulator and they contain xcodeproj. As a QA, I dont have the source code, only .ipa file. :(
Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set 3 variables:

```
$ DEVICE_TARGET=<UDID> \
    DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://<ip>:37265 \
    BUNDLE_ID=com.example.YourApp cucumber
```

The device and the host computer should be on the same network.

The .ipa must be installed on your device.

You can do this in Xcode by dragging-and-dropping in the Device Manager window or with a third-party tool like ideviceinstaller (available with homebrew).

You should *never* set `NO_LAUNCH`.

http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html#label-NO_LAUNCH

You also need to enable you device for develop and turn on UIAutomation in the Settings.app > Developer.

1. [Enabling device for development](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics#6-enable-development-after-upgrading-devices-to-8)
2. [RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics#7-errnoeintr-interrupted-system-call)

**UPDATE** In response to this question, I rewrote the [Testing on Physical Devices](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Testing-on-Physical-Devices) Calabash iOS wiki page.  Wow, that content was ancient!

Answer (score -1):

As long as the file is build with calabash then that is not a problem. You just call cucumber with APP_BUNDLE_PATH to where ever your .ipa file is and should be all set.

But you should be aware that .ipa needs to be build to match the target you run the tests on.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I actually run it with DEVICE_TARGET and BUNDLE_ID instead of APP_BUNDLE_PATH.
Anyway, dont you have any idea that when I do a action like 'touch', the app crashed and error say: A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)

Comment: Andy I believe I did answer your question. However in your comment it seems to me you raise a new question. If you want to rephrase your question please do so.